# socket.io получить rooms и подключенные к ним сокеты

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

имеется такой код:

```
var static = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
var file = new(static.Server)();
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(1234);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('room', function (room ) {

    socket.room = room;
    socket.join(socket.room);

    socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('room', room);
});
```

как получить данные о комнатах?

Comment: какие именно данные? Вон же сами св-во добавляете `room` в сокет, из него и получайте

Comment: я добавляю для текущего сокета, а необходимо получить для всех которые есть, что-то вроде io.sockets.adapter.rooms

Comment: @Sergey, вы сами ответили на свой вопрос.
io.sockets.adapter.rooms

Answer (score 1):

получить rooms можно так:
`let rooms = Object.keys(socket.rooms);`